# Fedora 35 GNOME Wayland - External monitor different size, different resolution. Laptop screen text seems blurry

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, fedora, gnome

I just hooked up a 24" Dell to my laptop and got it properly configured for the most part.

I'm having some issue with resolution and scaling, however. My laptop screen is almost lower-resolution or quality. Text seems to be just a little less crisp. The laptop native resolution is 2560x1440, the external screen is 1920x1080. I'm having a hard tie figuring out if it's a matter of setting the laptop to 1920x1080 and adjusting scaling, none of the scaling seems to make the text properly crisp.

Answer (score 1):

I used some common sense and realized if the scale isn't a multiple of 100% it's probably rounding off pixels in the text and making it look weird.